# Using LINQ's "into" keyword to group join not returning collection

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, linq, join

So I am fairly new to LINQ and have ran into an issue that I have not been able to find a solution for.

I was reading through the LINQ guide on msdn when I saw an article on Group Joins.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-grouped-joins

I read through the page and thought that it was exactly what I needed to complete my query. For my query, I am calling Table A which includes an ID that I use to join with a contacts table. The ID from the contacts table is then used to join with Table C on the same ID. Table C holds a Child ID that is then used to join back with the contacts table to retrieve a list of contacts. The contacts primary ID's are used to join with a phone number table. Contacts can have multiple phone numbers.

```
var query = (from a in db.TableA
                     join b in db.Contacts on a.PrimaryID equals b.PrimaryID
                     join c in db.tableC on b.PrimaryID equals c.ParentPrimaryID
                     join d in db.Contacts on c.ChildID equals d.PrimaryID
                     join e in db.TablePhoneNbrs on d.PrimaryID equals e.PrimaryID into gj
                     where a.PrimaryID == id
                     select new
                     {
                         PrimaryId = d.PrimaryId,
                         FirstName = d.FirstName,
                         LastName = d.LastName,
                         phhoneNbrs = gj
                     });
```

So from the article, I read that if you join two tables and then call "into" after the join, it will store the results of the query into whatever variable you specify as a collection. So in the query above, I tried joining the individual contacts with their single/multiple phone number(s) and then calling "into" to return a collection, instead of duplicating the contact for each number, but it failed. Instead of returning a collection of phone numbers for contacts with multiple numbers, it just duplicated the contact for each number that was returned.

So then I tried reducing the query and instead using a specific contact ID number and testing it out with just a single result.

```
var query2 = (from a in db.Contacts
     join b in db.TablePhoneNbrs on a.PrimaryID equalsb.PrimaryID into gj
     where a.PrimaryID == 1234
     select new
     {
         PrimaryID = a.PrimaryID,
         FirstName = a.FirstName,
         LastName = a.LastName,
         phhoneNbrs = gj
      }).ToList();
```

And this worked! So when I executed the query with a single contact ID, it correctly returned the contact and their two phone numbers as an array attached to the one contact object.

My question is if I am doing something wrong with the first query that is causing it to fail?

**UPDATE: With a much better example!**
So this is pretty much exactly how the relations work with the tables. This example appears to work, though. Query2 is the one that fails me at work. When it returns a contact, instead of storing the number in a collection and assigning it to Number variable, it duplicates the contact for each number that it has.

```
class Contact
{
    public int primaryID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

class TableC
{
    public int parentID { get; set; }
    public int childID { get; set; }
}

class TablePhoneNbr
{
    public int primaryID { get; set; }
    public string phoneNbr { get; set; }
}

class TableEmail
{
    public int primaryID { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Contact mainContact = new Contact { primaryID = 1, name = "My Test Code" };
        Contact Jim = new Contact { primaryID = 2, name = "Jim" };
        Contact Bob = new Contact { primaryID = 3, name = "Bob" };
        Contact Ashley = new Contact { primaryID = 4, name = "Ashley" };
        Contact Mary = new Contact { primaryID = 5, name = "Mary" };

        TableC child1 = new TableC { parentID = 1, childID = 2 };
        TableC child2 = new TableC { parentID = 1, childID = 3 };
        TableC child3 = new TableC { parentID = 1, childID = 4 };
        TableC child4 = new TableC { parentID = 1, childID = 5 };

        TablePhoneNbr Nbr1 = new TablePhoneNbr { primaryID = 2, phoneNbr = "123456" };
        TablePhoneNbr Nbr2 = new TablePhoneNbr { primaryID = 2, phoneNbr = "999999" };
        TablePhoneNbr Nbr3 = new TablePhoneNbr { primaryID = 3, phoneNbr = "888888" };
        TablePhoneNbr Nbr4 = new TablePhoneNbr { primaryID = 4, phoneNbr = "777777" };

        TableEmail Email1 = new TableEmail { primaryID = 2, email = "Hello World" };
        TableEmail Email2 = new TableEmail { primaryID = 3, email = "Goodbye World" };
        TableEmail Email3 = new TableEmail { primaryID = 4, email = "Testing1" };
        TableEmail Email4 = new TableEmail { primaryID = 5, email = "Testing2" };

        // Create two lists.
        List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact> { mainContact, Jim, Bob, Ashley, Mary };
        List<TableC> relations = new List<TableC> { child1, child2, child3, child4 };
        List<TablePhoneNbr> numbers = new List<TablePhoneNbr> { Nbr1, Nbr2, Nbr3, Nbr4 };
        List<TableEmail> emails = new List<TableEmail> { Email1, Email2, Email3, Email4 };

        // Create a list where each element is an anonymous type
        // that contains the person's first name and a collection of 
        // pets that are owned by them.
        var query = from primary in contacts
                    join relation in relations on primary.primaryID equals relation.parentID
                    join person in contacts on relation.childID equals person.primaryID
                    join number in numbers on person.primaryID equals number.primaryID into gj
                    select new { FirstName = person.name, Number = gj };

        foreach (var v in query)
        {
            // Output the owner's name.
            Console.WriteLine("{0}:", v.FirstName);
            // Output each of the owner's pet's names.
            foreach (TablePhoneNbr number in v.Number)
                Console.WriteLine("  {0}", number.phoneNbr);
        }

        var query2 = from primary in contacts
                    join relation in relations on primary.primaryID equals relation.parentID
                    join person in contacts on relation.childID equals person.primaryID
                    join email in emails on person.primaryID equals email.primaryID
                    join number in numbers on person.primaryID equals number.primaryID into gj
                    select new { FirstName = person.name, Number = gj, Email = email.email };

        foreach (var v in query2)
        {
            // Output the owner's name.
            Console.WriteLine("{0}:", v.FirstName);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}:", v.Email);
            // Output each of the owner's pet's names.
            foreach (TablePhoneNbr number in v.Number)
                Console.WriteLine("  {0}", number.phoneNbr);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: In your original query you are joing `TableB` to `TablePhoneNbrs`, but in your test your are joining `TableA` to `TablePhoneNbrs`?

Comment: @NetMage Whoops, my apologies. I edited my post and renamed the tables. So in my second(test) query, I am joining right from the contacts table to the phone number table with a hard coded ID. In the first query I am started with an ID from a totally different object and using that to then retrieve an ID from contacts, which I then use to retrieve a collection of child ID's from Table C, and then from those Table C Child ID's, I go back to the contacts table and retrieve a collection of Contacts.

Comment: Can you explain why exactly do you need a **group join** and not a **left outer join** (for example) as described here? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins

Comment: Also, why are you using **LINQ** directly, why not utilize **Entity Framework** ? You could then generate the model from your DB and just navigate the model instead of doing joins, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj713564(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: @ironstone13 That would presumably be because he wants to return an `IEnumerable<>` of phone numbers associated with a single contact, which is not what Left Outer Join is for.

Comment: @ironstone13 In that example, when a person has multiple dogs it returns the person 3 times for each dog. My query has a similar issue where one contact may have multiple numbers, and rather than returning multiple records for the same user with different phone numbers, I was hoping to just return a collection of phone numbers attached to the contact. I was able to accomplish this by writing a sub-query, but using "into" seemed like it would be a better alternative.  I should also mention that I am fairly new to SQL in general, so I apologize if what I am trying to do is inefficient/wrong.

Comment: @Pilpod can you try running the first query using a record where `ChildId` is 1234 to match your simpler query? Perhaps you just have a data issue? Do you have LINQPad?

Comment: @NetMage So I tried just hard coding an ID with the first query, but rather than a collection, it is still returning two separate records for each phone number of that particular contact. I do not have LINQPad on this computer, I can download it when I get home tho.

Comment: Now I am thinking the group join is occurring at the bottom level of your joins, so if you have multiple paths to the same contact, you will get multiple records (occurring before the group join) each with the same group of numbers. In that case, you need a group by - or maybe a `Distinct`.

Comment: Try adding another `child32 = new TableC { parentID = 3, childID = 2 };` and then put `child32` in at the end of `relations`. I think you will see Jim shows up twice in your queries now, but only once in mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try pulling out your contacts and using `Distinct()` before you try to get their numbers:

```
var contacts = (from a in db.TableA
                where a.PrimaryID == id
                join b in db.Contacts on a.PrimaryID equals b.PrimaryID
                join c in db.tableC on b.PrimaryID equals c.ParentPrimaryID
                join d in db.Contacts on c.ChildID equals d.PrimaryID
                select new { d.PrimaryID, d.FirstName, d.LastName } ).Distinct();

var query = (from d in contacts
             join e in db.TablePhoneNbrs on d.PrimaryID equals e.PrimaryID into ej
             select new {
                 PrimaryId = d.PrimaryID,
                 FirstName = d.FirstName,
                 LastName = d.LastName,
                 phhoneNbrs = ej
             });
```

Note it may be be better to just run `Distinct` against the `PrimaryID`s and then lookup the `FirstName` and `LastName`, but that should run on the SQL side so I don't think it matters a lot.

Comment: @ Netmage Interesting, I will have to try this tomorrow morning and get back to you. I also updated my answer above with a modified version of the msdn Grouped Join example to look more like the tables I am working with.

Comment: So I tried this out and I am actually getting an exception when I run it. When I try calling distinct() on the contacts query, it says that the image data type cannot be selected as distinct because it is not comparable. And then if I run it without distinct I get back the duplicate contacts again for each unique phone number.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL

Comment: Your Contacts table must include an image column. I fixed the query.

Comment: So I downloaded LINQpad and setup the tables from my example. How do I reference the DB context when writing in C#?

Comment: You add the database connection to LINQPad and then select the connection for the query (or right-click the connection and pick New Query...). The query is a subclass of the context so all table properties are directly available. Expanding the connection on the left will show the names.

Comment: Pulling out the contacts into a variable first, and then retrieving the phone numbers within a second LINQ query worked!